# How to fix overfulled last cell

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you help to fix the next code, please? I would like to fix the last cell of this vector. As you can see the last cell color is overfulled.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{collcell}
    
     %The min, mid aund max values
    \newcommand*{\MinNumber}{-1.0}%
    \newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0} %
    \newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%
    
    %Apply the gradient macro
    \newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{
            \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)}
                \colorbox{blue!\PercentColor!white}{}
            \else
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)}
                \colorbox{red!\PercentColor!white}{}
            \fi
    }
    
    
    \newcolumntype{R}{|>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}p{1mm}<{\endcollectcell}}
    %\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1mm} % box size
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR|} \hline
    0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 0.33 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 0.33 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.67 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 0.67 & 1.0 & 0.3 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that this is not the last cell which is overfull but each one is. The last cell is not overwritten by a following one so you see the overfull.

Comment: Nice application of `collcell`' ! +1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using framed color boxes, I inserted 1 x 2mm rules.

The table was defined with zero vertical padding, zero column width, and `\tabcolsep` equal to the width of the box, so the rules will fit. The height of the cell is determined by the height of the boxes.

[image: w8]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

%The min, mid aund max values
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{-1.0}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0.0} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%

\newlength{\Bwidth} % width ahd height of the boxes
\newlength{\Bheight}    
\setlength{\Bwidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\Bheight}{2mm}   

%Apply the gradient macro
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{% using rules
    \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)}
        \color{blue!\PercentColor!white}\rule{\Bwidth}{\Bheight} 
    \else
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)}
        \color{red!\PercentColor!white}\rule{\Bwidth}{\Bheight}
    \fi
}

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}wc{0mm}<{\endcollectcell}} % zero width 

\begin{document}    

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\Bwidth} % equal to box width
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.0} % zero vertical padding

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt} 
\addtolength{\Bwidth}{-1.6\arrayrulewidth}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|*{32}{@{\hspace*{-\arrayrulewidth}}T|@{\hspace*{-0.6\arrayrulewidth}}}|} % adjust hspace to center
    \hline
    0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 0.33 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 0.33 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.67 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.33 & 0.67 & 1.0 & 0.3 \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`\fboxsep`  sets the separation all around the box, so it is a square.

Try in your code

`\newcolumntype{R}{|>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}wc{0mm}<{\endcollectcell}}`

and

`\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}` to see whats going on.

[image: x]

Then use    `\colorbox{blue!\PercentColor!white}{}\hspace*{3.4pt}`

to get

[image: y]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, than you actually looking for showed image. It can be simple drawn as `tikzpicture` with chain of nodes, which colors are defined in `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {draw, fill=blue!#1!white, minimum width=2mm, minimum height=7mm,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                 node contents={}, on chain}
                        ]
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \i using 100*\x] in {
    0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.33, 0.33, 0.0, 0.33, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.33, 0.33, 0.0, 0.33, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.67, 0.0, 0.0,  0.33, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.33, 0.67, 1.0,  0.3}
\node[N=\i];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]